# Strong params sent, received and then mysteriously changed (Ruby and jQuery)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have no idea why this is happening, but it happens consistently after a page reload. I send `credit_amount` in my `params`, the controller gets them, but when updating the found record it somehow reverts to 0. Its bizarre.

Here is what the server log has:

```
Processing by CustomersController#update as JSON
Parameters: {"id"=>"89", "credit_amount"=>"$75.01"}
Shop Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Customer Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 89]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
Customer Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "customers" WHERE 
("customers"."fresh_customer_id" = '6474232467' AND "customers"."id" != 89) 
LIMIT 1
```

This is the interesting part, up until here the `credit_amount` was $75.01 and now below its 0.0:

```
SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "customers" SET "credit_amount" = ?, "updated_at" = ? 
WHERE "customers"."id" = ?  [["credit_amount", 0.0], 
["updated_at", "2017-04-25 22:25:57.428297"], ["id", 89]]
```

And this is the Ruby controller that receives and processes the data:

```
def update
  @customer = Customer.find(customer_params)
  update_amount = params["credit_amount"].to_f
  @customer.update(credit_amount: update_amount)
  render json: {id: customer_params, credit_amount: update_amount}
end
```

Comment: Could be that you are using a string and your db expects a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$` from amount before calling `to_f`. Something like this could help:

```
update_amount = params["credit_amount"].tr("$", "").to_f
```

Comment: eagle eye Gerry! Thank you much, that's exactly what it was. I just thought I was going crazy.